# Can anyone tell me why this occur MySQL syntax error?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
app.get('/delete_server',function(req,res){
    var before_page = req.query.before;
    var title = req.query.title;
    var sql = 'delete from ? where title=?';

    conn.query(sql,[before_page,title],function(err,rows,fields){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log(rows[0]);
            res.redirect('/menu/'+before_page);
        }
    })
})
```

I'm trying to make deleting server using querystring and sql query.
But it doesn't work. Console say it's SQL syntax error.
I think the problem is before_page variable.
SQL query become `delete from 'japan' where title='test'`
I think the 'japan' is wrong.

What should I do?

Comment: do you have any table with name `japan`?, If Yes, then correct syntax is `delete from japan where title='test'`

Comment: You can't substitute table names as parameters.

Comment: To add to the comment by @FrankerZ, your can't use a `?` placeholder for the table name.  Allowing this would be a security risk, because then potentially someone from the outside could decide which table gets delete run on it.  So, you'll have to hard code the table name.

Comment: I fixed it by rebuilding sql variable!!

Comment: @정성진 You should add an answer below, and mark it as accepted (To help future readers, who may stumble upon this question).

Comment: I changed it to 'delete from '+before_page+'where title=?'

Comment: @biegeleisen thats new to me. But what is for sure is that prepared statements need a tablename so that the same query can be run again and again with variable data. That doesnt work if the table varies as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes, the JavaScript library uses [MySQL prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to run your query. The documentation of the [`PREPARE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html) MySQL statement explains:

> Parameter markers can be used only where data values should appear, not for SQL keywords, identifiers, and so forth.

This means you cannot use `?` as a placeholder for command names (`SELECT`, `DELETE` etc), MySQL keywords (`FROM`, `AND` etc) or functions (`MIN()`, `SUBSTR()` etc), database names, table names or field names. Only the values can be replaced this way.

The solution for your code is:

```
var sql = 'delete from `'+before_page+'` where title=?';

conn.query(sql, [title], function(err, rows, fields) {
   // ...
}
```

Or, with ES5 and newer, you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
var sql = `delete from \`${before_page}\` where title=?`;
```

You have to be sure that the value of `before_page` is a valid table name. If you get it from the request your code is wide open to SQL injection.

Check the input value against a whitelist of table names or, even better, do not leak the table names outside the application; use generic names for the entities you handle and keep a mapping between the public name and the table name.

Find the table name by looking up the value of `req.query.before` into this map. Reject the operation if the input value is not in the map.

Answer (score 0):

I changed variable 'sql' to:

```
'delete from '+before_page+' where title=?'
```

Comment: Just be aware, you open your script up to some very nasty SQL injection at that point. What if I set `before_page` to `users /*`? Now your query becomes `delete from users /* where title=?`, and I've just deleted every user from your database. **This is VERY bad**, especially because `before_page` is coming directly from the query string (User input).

Comment: Ok I got it ! Thank you!